# Full page popup or flyout from a Page using hamburger menu

Tags: uwp, uwp-xaml, windows-community-toolkit

I am writing a Windows UWP app using `Hamburger` menu (from UWP toolkit) in a common shell page and navigating to all pages in app using the frame defined in shell page.

Now I want a common page to be shown in full screen mode without the hamburger menu and i want this same page to be used in many views with back stack enabled to take me to the same page from where this is opened.

I am not sure of what control or template to use in this scenario, I am pretty new to XAML development. Can anyone help with this?

Comment: From where do you want to open this common page? Hamburger menu's content page or from Hamburger menu's option item? Maybe post some codes about what you are currently doing?